# Why does cpplint not spot missing semicolons?

Tags: c++, cpplint

I have been using linters in NodeJS for a while `eslint` and have started using `cpplint` on my Arduino libraries in C++. It does not seem to pick up some fundamentals such as missing semicolons (but it does identify braces on the wrong line). It also doesn't seem to differentiate between spaces and tabs for indentation or badly indented code in the implementation file.

Coming from a NodeJS background, `cpplint` seems to be missing a lot of checks or am I completely missing the point?

Comment: Probably because your compiler won't be able to not spot them.

Comment: Thanks, I realise this but I was hoping that the linter should pick this up rather than having to go through a compile process before it was spotted. Should I just assume this is part of the pain in using C++?

Comment: Parsing C++ is *hard*. *Most* syntactic elements do double or triple duty, so trying to identify what you meant when given an ill-formed program is an AI level task

Answer (score 1):

`cpplint` only checks code style based on [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html). As long as I know, it won't check syntax error. If we look on [cpplint.py](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/blob/master/cpplint.py) implementation, we won't found any rule of regex govern about missing semicolons. And about indentation, as long as the whitespace width is even and not tabs, `cpplint` will pass it.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it won't even flag up if the whitespace is uneven, I shoved in a load of tabs on one line and it failed to pick this up. This is why I'm not sure if there are some settings I am missing (surely Google would require consistent indentation!!).

Comment: @MarkTyers - You're assuming more of the google style guide than is actually true.  Have a look at the google style guide, which Tirtadwipa linked to.  It does not say anything about extra whitespace on a line (other than at the end).